# [ask]monitor mode unsuccessful on android(arodump-ng wlan0)

Tags: android

When trying to enable monitor mode on lava Iris X1, usually with bcmon firmware and tools, there is a problem.
Actually, [B]Lava Iris X1 uses bcm4330[/B], but why does it not support?
Finally, I tried it from command line.

**The problem is "Cannot find wireless tools, exiting"**
**Here is the output:**

```
$su
#LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/data/com.bcmon.bcmon/files/libs

#LD_PRELOAD=/data/data/com.bcmon.bcmon/files/libs/libfake_driver.so sh

bmon_wrapper_loaded

#cd /data/data/com.bcmon.bcmon/files/tools

#./enable_bcmon
bmon_wrapper_loaded
bmon_wrapper_loaded
bmon_wrapper_loaded
bmon_wrapper_loaded
bmon_wrapper_loaded

#./airodump-ng wlan0 
bmon_wrapper_loaded
Cannot find wireless tools, exiting.
#
```

It seems that monitor mode enabled successfully, right?
However, when trying to run ./airodump-ng wlan0 **"Cannot find wireless tools, exiting."** :(

What should I do now? 
Can anybody help and point the reason of this problem?
Can it actually be possible?
Really need your help and suggestions/
Thanks in advance